# my code is perfect but idont now why i found problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my source of code. Every thing works fine for him in the video (see link) but not for me.

[Edeonics learning solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XccOs0tWngg&list=PLDmvslp_VR0wkiclky6vj6SSDx-N2QE9z&index=18)

> HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML5 | SNAKE GAME</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    </head>


    <body>
       <div class="container">
       <div id="overlay">
           Your Final Score : <span id="final_score"></span>
           <br />
           <a onclick="window.location.reload()" href="#">Click to play again</a>
           <!--End Of overlay-->
        </div>
           <canvas id="myCanvas">
            <p>Sorry, your browser dosn't support Canvas</p>
        </canvas>
        <div id="stats">
           <div class="score"></div>
           <div class="high_score"></div>
           <button id="reset_score" onclick="resetScore()">Rest score</button>
            <!--state-->
        </div>
      <!--End of container-->
</div>

           <!--Jquery-->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!--My JS-->
        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

> CSS

```
body{
    background: black url(snack.jpg)  no-repeat top center;
    font-family: arial;

}
a{
    color : currentColor;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#myCanvas{
            width : 600px ;
            height : 400px;
            border: 1px solid limegreen;
    background: rgba(100,50,100,0.5);
        }
.container{
    margin : 30px auto 0 auto;
    width : 610px;
    overflow : auto;
    position : relative;

}
#stats{
    width:590px;
    background: #cfa;
    padding : 5px;
    font-size : 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom : 5px;
    overflow: auto;

    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
.score{
    width : 25%;
    height : 50px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    float :left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    background : white;
    text-align: center;

}
#reset_score{
    padding : 10px;
    float : right;
background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
#overlay{
    display : none;
    color : limegreen;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align:center;
    position : absolute;
    top : 170px;
    left : 180px;
    opacity: 1;
}
#overlay a{
    display :block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    padding : 15px;
}
#overlay a:hover{
    background: #eee;
    color: darkgreen;
    -webkit-transition: background 17s;
    transition : background 17s;
    transition : color 17s;

}
```

I guess here is where I have the problem

> JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Intialize variables
    var canvas, ctx, w, h, d, food, score, speed, /*body of snake*/ snake_array, color;
    //End of intialize var

    //full 
    /*take the first cnvas element*/
    canvas = $("#myCanvas")[0];
    /*2D*/
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    w = canvas.width();
    h = canvas.height();
    cw = 15; /*size snake rect*/
    speed = 180;
    d = "right";
    color = "green";
    //End of variables
    //functions
    function init() {
        create_snake();
        create_food();
        score = 0;
        if (typeof game_loop != "undefined") {
            clearInterval(game_loop);

        }
        game_loop = setInterval(paint, speed);
        //End of fnction init()
    }
    //End of functions

    //Code
    init();
    //End of Code


    function create_snake() {
        //length of the snake
        var length = 5;
        snake_array = [];
        /*mod*/
        for (var i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            //push one square in body of snake
            snake_array.push({
                x: i,
                y: 0
            });
            //End of loop
        }
        //End of snacke func
    }

    function create_food() {
        food = {
            //random food in the screen 
            x: Math.round(Math.random() * (w - cw) / cw),
            y: Math.round(Math.random() * (h - cw) / cw)
                //End of food object
        };
        //End of creat_food func
    }
    //drawing the snake
    function paint() {
        //paint canvas
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        //border of canvas
        ctx.strockeStyle = "white";
        ctx.strockeRect(0, 0, w, h);
        //movement snack
        //draw snack
        var nx = snake_array[0].x;
        var ny = snake_array[0].y;
        //direction of snack
        if (d == 'right') {
            nx++;
        } else if (d == 'left') {
            nx--;
        } else if (d == 'up') {
            ny--;
        } else if (d == 'down') {
            ny++;
        }
        //Collide code when loosing
        if (nx == -1 || ny == -1 || nx == w / cw || ny == h / cw || check_collision(nx, ny, snake_array)) {
            init();
            return;
        }
        //Snake eat food
        var tail;
        if (nx == food.x && ny == food.y) {
            tail = {
                x: nx,
                y: ny
            };
            score++;
            //create  new random food
            create_food();
        } else {
            //remove square from the body of snake
            tail = snake_array.pop();
            tail.x = nx;
            tail.y = ny;
        }
        //add a new square to the body of the snake
        snake_array.unshift(tail);

        for (var i = 0; i < snake_array.length; i++) {
            var c = snake_array[i];
            paint_cell(c.x, c.y);
            //End for
        }
        //Paint cell
        paint_cell(food.x, food.y);

        //check score and show if score more than high score wil replace him
        checkscore(score);

        //End of paint func
    }

    function paint_cell(x, y) {
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(x * cw, y * cw, cw, cw);
        ctx.strockeStyle = "white";
        ctx.strockeRect(x * cw, y * cw, cw, cw);
        //End of paint_cell func
    }

    function check_collision(x, y, array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i.x == x && array[i].y == y]) {
                /*if(array[i].x == x && array[i].y == y){}*/
                return true;
            }
            //End of for loop
        }
        return false;
        //End of check collision func
    }


    //End of document
});
```

Comment: What's the problem you have and what are you trying to do?

Comment: Please reduce your code down to be as minimal as possible. Also "my code is perfect" is a statement which is **never** true.

Answer (score 1):

Several errors that i have noticed.

1. Move `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" </script>` to head and add an `async` attribute if needed.
2. Correct `w = canvas.width();` and `h = canvas.height();` as `w = canvas.width;` and `h = canvas.height;`
3. Replace all `ctx.strockeStyle` and `ctx.strockeRect` to `ctx.strokeStyle` and `ctx.strokeRect`
4. `checkscore()` function is not defined.

Comment: var canvas is a jquery object, so wouldn't canvas.width return a function instead of actual width?

Comment: No it is a proper DOM element since assigned as `canvas = $("#myCanvas")[0]` so `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` are properties. Please check HTML5 Canvas DOM element properties at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement#Properties

Comment: I just tried this by creating canvas element via firebug, then var x = $("#myCanvas")... then x.width returns the function, and x.width() returns a width value

Comment: ah I see... the difference is using [0] to select the first matching element... weird... as an id is supposed to be unique anyway

Comment: @yezzz The jQuery document (https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) says "Calling jQuery() (or $()) with an id selector as its argument will return a jQuery object containing a collection of either zero or one DOM element." Well i actually never use jQuery but at the end of the day a canvas element is a canvas element and it's width and height property is just a numerical value.

Comment: Thanks for that info Redu

Comment: I should add that both with and without [0] it returns an object, but they are different. I guess the important word here is "collection". That jQuery collection will not treat that canvas element as such even if that canvas element is the only element inside that collection.

Comment: Thanx but dont work and i drop it thanx alote